# floating anchor tag in Semantic UI

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I would like to know how to float an anchor tag using Semantic UI.

This is what I have tried to do so far:

```
<a href="somePath" class="ui right floated">someText</a>
```

But it does not work. I couldn't find enough documentation about how to float an element. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think most of the Semantic UI components revolve around the idea of using styled `<div>` tags to achieve some desired intent. What kind of UI element were you after? You can use the class `right floated` on a range of items e.g. `ui message` or `ui label`.